# error: request for member 'data' in something not a structure or union|

Tags: c, struct, dereference

I'm trying to practice Binnary trees.
I created a struct for node, allocated it for the root and also allocated space for the left son.
I built a function that returnes the size of the tree but it seems there is an error while trying to initialize the left son's variables.

the main function:

```
int main()
{
node* root = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));//allocate space for root
root->data = 7;
root->left = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));//allocate space for left son of root
root->right = NULL;

root->left.data = 8;//ERROR HERE!
root->left.left = NULL;//ERROR HERE!
root->left.right = NULL;//ERROR HERE!


printf("size of tree: %d\n", sizeOfTree(root));
return 0;
}
```

the node struct:

```
typedef struct
{
int data;
struct node* left;
struct node* right;
}node;
```

The Errors i get:

```
error: request for member 'data' in something not a structure or union|
error: request for member 'left' in something not a structure or union|
error: request for member 'right' in something not a structure or union|
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: left and right are `struct node *` so to access their member data, need to use -> not . ..

Comment: also `typedef struct` --> `typedef struct node`

Comment: A pointer to a structure is a pointer to a structure, no matter nesting level. And getting a member when you have a pointer to a structure you use the arrow `->`. You already know this, as you use it in e.g. `root->left`.

Comment: Why **(node*)** malloc(sizeof(node)); ??

Comment: Still doesn't work. Do you mean somthing like root->left->data?

Comment: If i'm doing 
    `root->left->data = 8;`
    `root->left->left = NULL;`
    `root->left->right = NULL;`

I'm getting a new error for those lines:

    |error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got error there because you try to access that pointer with **.** instead of **->**.
Also **typedef struct** should be **typedef struct node**.

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
}node;


int main(void){
    node* root = malloc(sizeof(node));//allocate space for root
    root->data = 7;
    root->left = malloc(sizeof(node));//allocate space for left son of root
    root->right = NULL;

    root->left->data = 8;//ERROR HERE!
    root->left->left = NULL;//ERROR HERE!
    root->left->right = NULL;//ERROR HERE!


    printf("size of tree: %d\n", sizeOfTree(root));
    return 0;
}
```

Don't cast **malloc** because return of malloc is **void***.

Comment: @Michi  What is difference between `typedef struct` and `typedef struct node` ?